# How to compare std::variant of custom classes?

Tags: c++, std, std-variant

1.It's my classes:

```
struct SymbolToken {
    std::string name;
};

struct QuoteToken {
};

struct ConstantToken {
    int value;
};
```

2. I have a following typedef:

```
typedef std::variant<SymbolToken, QuoteToken, ConstantToken> Token;
```

3. I wanna write an assert:

```
assert(Token{ConstantToken{4}} == Token{ConstantToken{4}}) // fine
assert(Token{ConstantToken{3}} == Token{ConstantToken{4}}) // exception
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: Assert failure rarely throws an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `==` on the contained types.

For Quote, always return true.

Probably also implement `!=` as a matter of sanity.